# What mean a number after HTTP Status Code in tomcat 7.0 log file?

Tags: logging, http, tomcat, status

What mean a number after HTTP Status Code in tomcat 7.0 log file (e.g localhost_access_log.2016-10-27.txt)?

For example, 1147 after 404 in:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [27/Oct/2016:11:47:03 +0300] "GET /XXX.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1147
```

Comment: number of bytes transfered ?

Comment: Yes! Looks like it is a number of bytes sent by tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

A number after HTTP Status Code in tomcat 7.0 log file is

**a number of bytes sent by tomcat**.

For example,

if 19327 bytes were sent by tomcat, then there will be written:

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [28/Oct/2016:15:56:35 +0300] "GET XXX HTTP/1.1" 200 19327

Comment: Answered by @Archemar (in comments).